# rabbitvcs + git + add files

Tags: 14.04, git, svn, rabbitvcs, cms

I'm using RabbitVCS with git on my Ubuntu 14.04 computer.

My problem is that I don't see any option in Nautilus (plugin) to add new files in the contextual menu.

Previously, I was using RabbitVCS with SVN and it had an option to Add the files.

How do you Add file to the local repository with RabbitVCS ?
(Normally, I do: Add file, then commmit, then Push)

For now my workaround is to do: "git add ." in command line but I would like to work completely in RabbitVCS.

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer to my own question !

I had to do a "Commit" from RabbitVCS and then select/check the checkbox "Show unversionned files" and select the files I wanted to add on the server.

Finally, I had to do the "Push" and my files were on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The fact that the checkbox for showing unversioned file was checked while those were hidden confused me at first.